# How to get the number of items in a qcombobox?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I check the number of items in combobox in the Qt library?

Answer (score 9):

For the `QComboBox` widget (or the `ComboBox` QML element for that matter), it's the [`count`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#count-prop) property.

As an aside, for future reference, this sort of stuff is relatively easy to find out if you just plug `qt qcombobox` into your favourite search engine and look for the first hit starting with `https://doc.qt.io/`.